# UITextField text jumps iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

Link for previous question:
[UITextField text jumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765372/uitextfield-text-jumps)

Briefly:
I have `ViewController` with 2 `UITextField` elements. When loginField is firstResponder, after

```
self.passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

text in login field jumps to the top left corner and back. And what's more strange: this glitch reproduces only first time, then you need recreate `ViewController` to observe this behavior

Here is video of the glitch http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=6nsemw%3E&s=8#.VgVb3cuqpHx

## I ended up with this (doesn't work for iOS 9):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField === self.loginField {
        self.loginField.resignFirstResponder()
        // Shitty workaround. Hi, Apple!
        self.loginField.setNeedsLayout()
        self.loginField.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Is there anybody who has been stucked with this bug? Any suggestions?

## Keyboard notifications handlers

My main view is UIScrollView, for which I change bottom space to superview, so user can scroll all the content even when keyboard is shown

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification : NSNotification) {
    let keyboardInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue
    let animDuration = keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue!

    UIView.animateWithDuration(animDuration, animations: {
        self.scrollViewBottom.constant = keyboardFrame.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let offsetY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.loginButton.frame) + 10 - self.scrollView.frame.height
        if offsetY > 0 {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY)
        }
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification : NSNotification) {
    self.scrollViewBottom.constant = 0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

As I discovered keyboard notifications in iOS7, 8 and 9 very differ. So, in iOS 9 notifications are sent while changing firstResponder even if keyboard will not Show/Hide. Also, when I change firstResponder with tapping on textField (not tapping Next on keyboard which is handled by my code), there is only KeyboardWillShow notification and no KeyboardWillHide. And as for me, userInfo has some trash frame values, here is log when changing first responder using next button (works ok, without glitches):

> 2015-10-07 12:54:13.870 keyboardWillHide:
>   [UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey: NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}},
>   UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey: NSPoint: {160, 460},
>   UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey: NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 216}},
>   UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey: NSPoint: {160, 676},
>   UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey: 0.25,
>   UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey: 1, UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey: NSRect:
>   {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}, UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey: 7]
>   2015-10-07 12:54:13.896 keyboardWillShow:
>   [UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey: NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}},
>   UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey: NSPoint: {160, 460},
>   UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey: NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}},
>   UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey: NSPoint: {160, 460},
>   UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey: 0.25,
>   UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey: 1, UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey: NSRect:
>   {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}, UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey: 7]

And here is log when I tap on the second textField:

> 2015-10-07 12:55:13.879
>   keyboardWillShow:[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey: NSRect: {{0, 352},
>   {320, 216}},     UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey: NSPoint: {160,
>   460},     UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey: NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320,
>   216}},     UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey: NSPoint: {160, 460},
>   UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey: 0.25,
>   UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey: 1, UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey: NSRect:
>   {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}, UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey: 7]

## Resolution

I discovered that I have another Keyboard Controller that receives keyboard notifications and make some animations. That's where the problem lies

Comment: How are you handling keyboard? Do you have registered notifications for keyboard will appear/hide? If yes can you post the code what you do there?

Comment: Tnx for the help, check edited post

Comment: You're getting will hide notification because you call resignFirstResponder() before becomeFirstResponder(), the "jumping" is caused by the animation in keyboardWillShow()

Comment: **For 2017**... Timur's solution below seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your edited question I can see this, when you tap next button on keyboard:

1. You're calling `resignFirstResponder()` and then `becomeFirstResponder()`. This calls `keyboardWillHide` notification and then `keyboardWillShow` notification
2. In `keyboardWillHide` you have `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` which layouts the view (and subviews - textfields) without animation.

Because of this the textfield layout is "fixed" and when you do animation in `keyboardWillShow` the text in textfield doesn't "jump" anymore, because you did layout in `keyboardWillHide`.

But when you just tap another textfield, only `keyboardWillShow` is called, layout is not "fixed" in textfield and when you animate the view, the text does a "jump" animation.

That's why it doesn't jump when you tap next on keyboard but it does jump when you just tap another textfield.

So I would advise to change it to this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField === self.loginField {
        self.passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification : NSNotification) {
    let keyboardInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue
    let animDuration = keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue!

    self.loginField.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.passwordField.layoutIfNeeded()

    if keyboardFrame.height != self.scrollViewBottom.constant {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animDuration, animations: {
            self.scrollViewBottom.constant = keyboardFrame.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            let offsetY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.loginButton.frame) + 10 - self.scrollView.frame.height
            if offsetY > 0 {
                self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: I even commented my keyboard notification handlers - glitch still persist

Comment: Wrapped like this UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
            self.loginField.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.passwordField.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
and not it works

Answer (score 6):

Tnx to [haluzak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678377/haluzak):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField === self.loginField {
        self.passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification : NSNotification) {
    let keyboardInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue
    let animDuration = keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue!

    UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
        self.loginField.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.passwordField.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

    if keyboardFrame.height != self.scrollViewBottom.constant {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animDuration, animations: {
            self.scrollViewBottom.constant = keyboardFrame.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            let offsetY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.loginButton.frame) + 10 - self.scrollView.frame.height
            if offsetY > 0 {
                self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The `performWithoutAnimation` part was key for me.

Answer (score 5):

I've faced same issue, when I was trying to change first responder. There is a better solution for this issue. Just implement UITextField subclass and used in places, where your text field can be animated (keyboard, first respond switching and so on).

```
@interface UITextFieldFixed : UITextField

@end

@implementation UITextFieldFixed

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    BOOL result = [super resignFirstResponder];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    return result;
}

@end
```

More info about issue: https://github.com/foundry/UITextFieldBug

Copy and paste for Swift3...

```
class UITextFieldFixed: UITextField {
    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let r = super.resignFirstResponder()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return r
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic Timur, thanks. I pasted in the same in Swift3 - feel free to edit or undo, Timur!

Comment: sent bounty for great answer here

Comment: Works great, seems like you don't need `setNeedsLayout` either.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your keyboard will show notification, BEFORE you do any animations:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
    self.yourTextField1.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.yourTextField2.layoutIfNeeded()
    //etc.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code you need to write for stop jumping of text. This is work for me.

`func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Workaround for the jumping text bug.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.layoutIfNeeded()
}`