# UITextField text moving unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Below is a demonstration of how the text in my text field is moving when the text field is active. By applying a background to the field, i found that only the text moves, not the whole text field itself. This is not happening to the text field above as well, only the bottom one

[image]

Comment: it happens with the secure Entry enabled  text field

Comment: Can you check if you have modified any property on losing the focus from the control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after search for this issue i  recommend to change your font to another font. but there is some way to prevent this issue :

you can use this :

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 [textField layoutIfNeeded]; //Fixes iOS 9 text bounce glitch
  //...other stuff
}
```

please check this links :

[Text in UITextField moves up after editing (center while editing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674566/text-in-uitextfield-moves-up-after-editing-center-while-editing)

[UITextField text jumps iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987046/uitextfield-text-jumps-ios-9)

Comment: The code did not solve the issue, but thank you i will change my font

Comment: @rohaldb , sorry if this code don't working for you , please notify me about the result, you can use Arial font :)

Comment: @rohaldb please tell me the result bro

Comment: The issue was the font. If i change to Arial, the issue goes away. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to font to Arial, helped me.

```
yourTextField.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(16))
```

Comment: This fixed a similar issue, that caused my text to jitter while I typed in a UITextField. System Font was doing something funny